# Background image for each cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to create an `UITableView` where each cell will have a background image and so far I am doing this:

```
//UITableViewController
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HomeTVCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = StaticData.HOME_ITEMS_TEXT[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: cell.frame);
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: StaticData.HOME_ITEMS_IMGS[indexPath.row])
    cell.backgroundView = UIView()
    cell.backgroundView?.addSubview(imageView)

    NSLog("Row: \(indexPath.row), Img: \(StaticData.HOME_ITEMS_IMGS[indexPath.row])")

    return cell
}
```

And `StaticData` contains:

```
static let HOME_ITEMS_TEXT = [
    "Get Inspired",
    "Places & Attractions",
    "Foods",
    "Tourist Map",
    "Recommended Tours",
    "Tips: Save Money",
    "Tips: Comfort",
    "Hotels",
    "Emergency",
    "Tourism Companies",
    "Travel Companies"
]

static let HOME_ITEMS_IMGS = [
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil",
    "AhsanMonzil"
]
```

But I'm only getting background image for the first cell. What am I missing?

Comment: you made a custom cell, did you also make a custom image view? or you try to use the default backgroundView property?

Comment: I didn't make any custom image view. Also I'm just using default `Basic` `Style` for cells.

Comment: @CoolBrain your not making it right, did you follow a tutorial or read the documentation ? or you are just guessing?

Comment: I wasn't following any tutorial rather than playing around. Sorry for my delay. Anyways got the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace code of below:

```
cell.backgroundView = UIView()
cell.backgroundView?.addSubview(imageView)
```

with:

```
cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before `return cell`